Cannot interrupt uboot "Hit any key to stop autoboot:" with pySerial
I have a python script that is supposed to run a Linux update on an iMX6 device. I can reboot Linux via serial connection. I can see the device rebooting (console output is transferred). However, when I encounter the line "Hit any key to stop autoboot:" in the serial output, a write command seems to get ignored.
import time
import serial


def reboot_and_update(port, baudrate=115200):
    # Open the serial connection
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=1,
                        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, xonxoff=True,
                        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    print(f"Connected to {port} at {baudrate} baud. Output:")
    ser.write(b"reboot\r")  # Send the command
    try:
        while True:
            # Read a line from the serial port
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
            if line:
                # Print the received line to the console
                print(f"{line}")

                # Check for the specific line to trigger actions
                if "Hit any key to stop autoboot:" in line:
                    print("Interrupt autoboot...")
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    ser.write(b"345ju\r")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    ser.write(b"run install_linux_fw_sd\r")  # Send the command

                # Check for the login prompt and wait 3 seconds
                elif "ccimx6ulsbc login:" in line:
                    print("Login prompt detected. Waiting for 3 seconds.")
                    time.sleep(3)

                    # If nothing else happens, close the connection
                    additional_line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
                    if not additional_line:
                        break
                    else:
                        # Print any additional lines received during the wait period
                        print(f"Received after login prompt: {additional_line}")
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay to prevent busy waiting

    finally:
        ser.close()
        print("Finished")

The output I receive:
  (py312) C:\...>python serialconn.py
Connected to COM5 at 115200 baud. Output:
reboot
Broadcast message from root@ccimx6ulsbc (ttymxc4) (Fri Mar  9 14:41:36 2018):
The system is going down for reboot NOW!
INIT: Switching to runlevel: 6
INIT: Sending processes configured via /etc/inittab the TERM signal
root@ccimx6ulsbc:~# Stopping syslogd/klogd: stopped syslogd (pid 639)
stopped klogd (pid 642)
done
Stopping Dropbear SSH server: stopped /usr/sbin/dropbear (pid 661)
dropbear.
Stopping bluetooth: bluetoothd.
Stopping Busybox ACPI daemon: done
stopping Busybox HTTP Daemon: httpd... no httpd found; none killed
Stopping Busybox NTP client/server: done
Stopping system message bus: dbus.
ModemManager[739]: <warn>  could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
ModemManager[739]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Stopping HOSTAP Daemon: hostapd.
Stopping tcf-agent: OK
ALSA: Storing mixer settings...
Unmounting remote filesystems...
Deconfiguring network interfaces... done.
Stopping NetworkManager: done
Stopping vsftpd server: done
Sending all processes the TERM signal...
Sending all processes the KILL signal...
Deactivating swap...
Unmounting local filesystems...
Rebooting...
U-Boot dub-2020.04-r7.1+gaf77921f51 (Jan 30 2024 - 12:53:20 +0000)
CPU:   i.MX6UL rev1.2 528 MHz (running at 396 MHz)
CPU:   Industrial temperature grade (-40C to 105C) at 68C
Reset cause: POR
DRAM:  1 GiB
MCA:   HW_VER=1  FW_VER=1.14
PMIC:  PFUZE3000 DEV_ID=0x30 REV_ID=0x11
NAND:  1024 MiB
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Model: Digi International ConnectCore 6UL SBC.
ConnectCore 6UL SOM variant 0x04: Industrial Ultralite 528MHz, 1GB NAND, 1GB DDR3, -40/+85C, Wireless, Bluetooth
Board version undefined, ID undefined
Boot device:  NAND
Net:   FEC0 [PRIME]
Fastboot: Normal
Normal Boot
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Interrupt autoboot...
ubi0: attaching mtd4
ubi0: scanning is finished
ubi0: attached mtd4 (name "linux", size 24 MiB)
ubi0: PEB size: 131072 bytes (128 KiB), LEB size: 126976 bytes
ubi0: min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048/2048, sub-page size 2048
ubi0: VID header offset: 2048 (aligned 2048), data offset: 4096
ubi0: good PEBs: 192, bad PEBs: 0, corrupted PEBs: 0
ubi0: user volume: 1, internal volumes: 1, max. volumes count: 128
ubi0: max/mean erase counter: 15/11, WL threshold: 4096, image sequence number: 0
ubi0: available PEBs: 0, total reserved PEBs: 192, PEBs reserved for bad PEB handling: 8
Loading file 'boot.scr' to addr 0x80800000...
Done
## Executing script at 80800000
## Loading kernel: zImage-ccimx6ulsbc.bin

...
So, seems like any input during the boot is somehow ignored.
I have tried to do the same thing with PuTTY, here it works. I have copied all the connection settings to my python script (but even with xonxoff disabled, it didn't work).
Can anybody help me here?

If the log output that you present here is to be believed, then you simply missed the moment to press any key ... the timeout (0) has already expired.

@Risto the timeout window is 2 seconds (counting 1, 0, gone).

Yes, and according to your log it looks like this:
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 and then
Interrupt autoboot... and then 100 ms later you try to send some text ...


U-Boot does not support the Xon/Xoff protocol. Please, use xonxoff=False.
As user Risto mentioned you should not use readline() but read single bytes.
You should use the U-Boot command line prompt to know when to write the U-Boot command.

    line = b''
    uboot = 0
    prompt = b'=>'
    try:
        while True:
            # Read a line from the serial port
            char = ser.read()
            if char == b'':
                continue
            if char[0] == 13:
                # Print the received line to the console
                print(f"{line.decode('utf-8').strip()}")
                line = b''
            line += char
            # Check for the specific line to trigger actions
            if uboot == 0 and b'Hit any key to stop autoboot:' in line:
                print("Interrupt autoboot...")
                ser.write(b'\r')
                uboot = 1
            elif uboot == 1 and prompt in line:
                ser.write(b"run install_linux_fw_sd\r")  # Send the command
                uboot = 2
            # Check for the login prompt and wait 3 seconds
            elif uboot == 2 and b'ccimx6ulsbc login:' in line:
                print("Login prompt detected. Waiting for 3 seconds.")


Your Python code obviously processes the
                    # Check for the specific line to trigger actions
                    if "Hit any key to stop autoboot:" in line:

after the countdown has finished.
The reasons for this is that the boot loader does a bit of terminal magic to display the countdown 2,1,0 and you are using readLine() which needs something like an end-of-line character (e.g. "\n") to understand that the line is finished.
You probably need to use read() with some additional logic instead, to get the text before the end-of-line character is sent and the Count down finishes.
